Authentication in Blazor Server Interactive
I am not able to implement a working authentication system in my Blazor .NET8 ServerInteractive application. I am quite new at web dev (I am more of a WinForm/WPF programmer)
I have search internet for now more that a full day but I can't figure out how to do it properly ans simply.
At the moment, I have kind of a working authentication but not "persistent". I have implemented a custom AuthenticationStateProvider like this :
public class AuthenticationManager(ILogger<AuthenticationManager> logger) : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
  private ClaimsPrincipal _user = new();

  public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
  {
    return Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_user));
  }

  public ClaimsPrincipal? LogInUser(string decryptedName, string decryptedPassword)
  {
    try
    {
      // Vérifier si un nom d'utilisateur et un mot de passe ont été fournis
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(decryptedName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(decryptedPassword))
      {
        // Recherche d'un utilisateur correspondant dans la base de données
        using DBInterface dbManager = new();
        TUser? dbUser = dbManager.GetAllUsers().FirstOrDefault(u => string.Compare(decryptedName, u.Name, true) == 0);

        // Vérification du mot de passe
        if (dbUser != null && Simple3Des.DecryptString(dbUser.PasswordHash) == decryptedPassword)
        {
          List<Claim> claims =
          [
            new(ClaimTypes.Name, decryptedName),
            new(ClaimTypes.Role, dbUser.AccessLevelEnu.ToString())
          ];
          ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

          _user = new(claimsIdentity);

          NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(GetAuthenticationStateAsync());
          return _user;
        }
      }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      logger!.LogError("Erreur dans {methodName} : {exceptionType} : {exceptionMessage}", $"{nameof(AuthenticationManager)}.{nameof(LogInUser)}", ex.GetType().Name, ex.Message);
      throw;
    }
    return null;
}

public void LogOutUser()
  {
    _user = new();
    NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(GetAuthenticationStateAsync());
  }
}

The login/logout is working, I can even navigate in my website and the user is retained but if I refresh the page (F5) or open a new tab the user is not logged any more. I do understand is normal because of the way my user is stored (private field of AuthenticationManager).
Now, the question is : how to make it work as expected?
I am quite sure it doesn't require much more but I am stuck...

The way it usually works is that users logs in using username and password and you send authentication cookie with the HttpResponse.
The authentication cookie is bound to your website and contains encrypted user name or user id.
The browser will remember the authentication cookie and send it with all requests to your website.
ASP.NET core app will then use authentication middleware to parse the authentication cookie. If it is valid, it sets ClaimsPrincipal to HttpRequest.
My suggestion would be:

Create login page using plain old MVC/Razor(.cshtml) pages.
HttpContext.SignInAsync() method to generate the authentication cookie
Require already authenticated user for all blazor pages. Othervise redirect to login page. The default AuthenticationManager in Blazor will use the ClaimsPrincipal from HttpContext.User which automatically resolved using AuthenticationMiddleware.

builder.Services.AddMvc();
builder.Services
    .AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();
...
var app = builder.Build();
...
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers(); //for login page. Alternatively app.MapRazorPages()
app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()
    .RequireAuthorization(); //blazor pages will always get already authenticated user


public class AuthController(ILogger<AuthController> logger, IHttpContextAccessor? httpContextAccessor, IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider) : Controller
{

  [HttpPost("/auth/login")]
  [AllowAnonymous]
  public async Task<IActionResult> LogInUser(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = "/")
  {
    //todo: validate user
    AuthenticationProperties authProperties = new()
    {
      AllowRefresh = true,
      IsPersistent = true,
    };
    await httpContextAccessor!.HttpContext!.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), authProperties);
    return Redirect(returnUrl);
  }
}

public class LoginViewModel
{
  public string UserName { get; set; } = "";
  public string Password { get; set; } = "";
}


As you can see in my other post link. I have tried this option and I though and still think now that there is a better solution somewhere.
But Atm it's the best solution that I have found.
I have a question, though: How can I call the POST method from razzor componant?

It the other post you said you call the /auth/login from razor component, which is completely different. I said that you won't even load any razor component until you are logged in.

I see... I need to be able to call login form from razzor component so this solution will not work. Thanks anyway !
